# Install Self Signed Certificate into Windows Machine for MSIX

Tags: windows, certificate, windows-installer, msix

I've created a self signed msix file and generated my key using MSIX Hero which seems to work fine. It created 3 files for me, of which 2 I know I need:

1. pfx file for signing
2. passwordless certificate that can be installed onto the target computer

I tried to install the certificate by double clicking and using automatic detection, but installing using the msix doesn't recognize the certificate. I then used MSIX Hero to install the same certificate, then I'm able to install using the MSIX.

This wouldn't be an ideal solution because I dont want to make my client's employee's install this app to install the certificate, so I'm guessing there must be a better way by double clicking or doing some other action to get the certificate installed.

What's the best way to install the self signed certificate?